# How to use elapsed time to code a function to manipulate DOM

Tags: javascript, html5, music, css, time

I'm a new software engineering student. I have a problem that I can't seem to get my head around. I am currently making a basic rhythm game like Guitar Hero using HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.

I managed to run an `elapsedTime` function that starts a timer running the moment you press start. But I am stuck thinking about how to code a function that uses that elapsed time and uses integers/floats from an array and drops notes according to that number in the array. Basically, comparing the numbers in the array to the current elapsed time and determining if it's the proper time to drop the note. Any suggestions or explanations will be greatly appreciated; thank you!

Code:

```js
/*hard coded array of notes, time to fall in milli seconds based on elapsed time
notesW = [1000,2000,3000,4000,5000]
notesE = [6000,7000,8000,9000,10000]
notesR = [11000,12000,13000,14000,15000]
*/
let elapsedTime = 0;
// Function to update elapsed time
function updateElapsedTime() {
    const currentTime = new Date().getTime();
    elapsedTime = Math.floor((currentTime - startTime) / 1000);
    document.querySelector('.elapsed_Time').innerText = `Elapsed Time: ${elapsedTime} seconds`;
}
```